# Estimate sum over squares $f(r)=\sum_{k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb Z; \vert k_1 \vert,\vert k_2\vert \ge r} \frac{1}{(k_1^2+k_2^2-k_1k_2)^2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

I want to upper-bound the following sum

$$f(r)=\sum_{k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb Z; \vert k_1 \vert,\vert k_2\vert \ge r} \frac{1}{(k_1^2+k_2^2-k_1k_2)^2}.$$

One simple way I could think of was to use polar coordinates and

$$f(R) \le \int_0^{2\pi} \int_R^{\infty} \frac{r}{r^4(1+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^2} \ dr d \theta.$$

This can be explicitly evaluated.

Can one find a better explicit estimate?

Comment: Writing $k_1^2+k_2^2-k_1k_2=(k_1-1)(k_2-1)-1$, this sum is larger than $2\left(\sum_{k \ge r}\frac{1}{(k-1)^2}\right)$, a little larger only for big values of $r$

Comment: @JeanMarie actually I need an upper bound though

Comment: In the integral, you've overloaded $r$ by having it as the function of the argument and as the integration variable. You should change them so they are distinct variables.

Comment: I don't think the upper bound is valid. You have $f(1) \approx 3.382$, but the integral is $\approx 0.865$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I corrected a typo in the integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum can be rewritten as $$2\sum_{k_1=r}^{\infty}\sum_{k_2=r}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}-k_{1}k_{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{1}{\left(k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}+k_{1}k_{2}\right)^{2}}\right)$$ for integer $r$. Each summand is decreasing, so an upper bound would be $$2\int_{r-1}^{\infty}\int_{r-1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}-k_{1}k_{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{1}{\left(k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}+k_{1}k_{2}\right)^{2}}\right)dk_2dk_1$$

This can be evaluated in closed form as $\frac{4(-3+\pi\sqrt{3})}{9(r-1)^2}$ for $r > 1$ which means $$f(r) \le \frac{4(-3+\pi\sqrt{3})}{9(r-1)^2}\approx 1.085(r-1)^{-2}$$

for integer $r > 1$.

Your upper bound on the other hand would give $$f(r) \le \frac{8\pi}{3\sqrt{3}r^2}\approx 4.837r^{-2}$$

Comment: how do you elevaluate this in cartesian coordiantes?

Comment: There's a clunky indefinite integral that you could manually find in terms of $\arctan$, but to be honest, I just chucked it in Mathematica.

Comment: can you give me the mathematica command that does the integral, cause I got stuck with that one...

Comment: ```2 Integrate[1/(k1^2 + k2^2 - k1*k2)^2 + 1/(k1^2 + k2^2 + k1*k2)^2, {k1, r - 1, Infinity}, {k2, r - 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> r > 1]```

Comment: perfect, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using something simple like

$a^2+b^2-ab
=(2a^2+2b^2-2ab)/2
=(a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2)/2
\ge (a^2+b^2)/2
$

makes each term at most

$4/(k_1^2+k_2^2)^2
$.

Comment: This is not an answer, this estimate is clearly worse than what I am doing